# TCPClient / Server - How to Send Data via TCP/IP ASCII Special Characters

Tags: vb.net, ascii, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have an application which currently sends requests via TCP/IP Port 6000, and waits for a Reply.

I have been given the Request / Reply Protocol, but cant seem to send ASCII Control Characters like SOH,SOT,EOT etc... 01,02,03.

This is what I receive via TCP Port 6000 which I can display in the Msgbox.
[Enquiry Message http://www.hcs-it.com/Enquiry.jpg](http://www.hcs-it.com/Enquiry.jpg)
And this is what I am meant to send back ...
[Enquiry Message http://www.hcs-it.com/Response.jpg](http://www.hcs-it.com/Response.jpg)

Here is my Class Code ...

```
Private Sub StartListen()
    Try
        ' Must listen on correct port- must be same as port client wants to connect on.
        Const portNumber As Integer = 6000
        Dim tcpListener As New TcpListener(portNumber)
        tcpListener.Start()
        ' Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...")
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "Waiting for Connection ...." & vbCrLf

        '
        '
        '    SOH <ID> STX <DATA> ETX <CKSUM> EOT
        '
        '
Top:

        'Accept the pending client connection and return a TcpClient initialized for communication. 
        Dim tcpClient1 As TcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()

        ' Get the stream
        Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient1.GetStream()
        ' Read the stream into a byte array
        Dim bytes(tcpClient1.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient1.ReceiveBufferSize))
        ' Return the data received from the client to the console.
        Dim clientdata As String = ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes)

        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & clientdata

        Dim soh As String = GetChar(clientdata, 1)
        Dim id As String = "010000000000000000"
        Dim stx As String = GetChar(clientdata, 20)
        Dim etx As String = GetChar(clientdata, 44)

        Dim ack As String = System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32("06", 16))

        Dim cksum As String = clientdata.Substring(44, 4)
        Dim eot As String = GetChar(clientdata, 49)

        Dim data As String = " 1Some Date        "
        Dim responseString As String = soh & id & stx & data & etx & cksum & eot & ack
        Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseString)
        networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & vbCrLf & responseString & vbCrLf

        tcpClient1.Close()
        tcpListener.Stop()

        GoTo Top

    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString())
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Try


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`ASCIIEncoding.Unicode` you should investigate that expression... This is equivalent to `Encoding.Unicode` which is not what you want (you want `ASCII`).

Also, you are ignoring the return value from `Read` which is a common mistake.

Comment: Thanks,I noticed that one and changed to
                Dim clientdata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)

Comment: Dont understand what return value I am ignoring ?

Comment: There's a call to networkStream.Read that returns you how many bytes actually were read. Your usage of ReceiveBufferSize is also a bug since that value is not the amount of data available.

Comment: OK, I think that I should start somewhere to understand this more, could you suggest a tutorial regrding TCP Comms for me, as I am not understanding then fundamentals of what I am doing wrong here and dont want to waste your time.

Comment: Good plan. Maybe http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/06/using-socket-as-connected-socket.html is a good start, I don't know. Most TCP code on the web is horrible.

Comment: I have look at some Tutorials and some of the Source on the Web and nothing does what I am looking for when it comes to Control Characters, as I do not seem to be able to send a response back to the TCPClient. Can anyone help me a get this seemingly simple program up and running, I am happy to make any contribution to PayPal Accounts ?? Tearing my hair out now. would appreciate your help.